# Performace Optimization for Comparing an Object to it's Own Table

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a performance issue where I am calling a list of items and then using a foreach loop to compare each record to other records in the same table. Is there a way to do this with one call to the database? Right now this query runs very slow when comparing to a large table.

I am using Entity Framework 5.

Here is an example:

```
var animals = new List<Animal>
{
    new Animal 
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Tiger",
        Birthday = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 9, 0, 0)
    },
    new Animal 
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Tiger",
        Birthday = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 20, 0, 0)
    },

    new Animal 
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Lion",
        Birthday = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 7, 0, 0)
    },

    new Animal 
    {
        Id = 4,
        Name = "Lion",
        Birthday = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 14, 0, 0)
    },

};

var animalsToCompareTo = animals.Where (a => a.Id == 2 || a.Id = 4);

foreach (var animalToCompareTo in animalsToCompareTo)
{
    bool isTheSecondTigerOfTheDay = animals.Any (a => a.Name == animalToCompareTo.Name &&
                                                    a.Birthday.Day == animalToCompareTo.Birthday.Day &&
                                                    a.Birthday.Month == animalToCompareTo.Birthday.Month &&
                                                    a.Birthday.Year == animalToCompareTo.Birthday.Year &&
                                                    a.Birthday < animalToCompareTo.Birthday
                                                    );  

    if (isTheSecondTigerOfTheDay)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The value assigned to `isTheSecondTigerOfTheDay` will be assigned both Tiger[ID=2] and Lion[ID=4] when this is run. Also, if you add another "Tiger" with a birthday before 2012/01/01 20:00, Tiger[ID=2] will still be assigned to `isTheSecondTigerOfTheDay` even though it is the third tiger. Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `animals` here is a stand-in for an Entity Framework query? If so, the first step would be to make sure that your table is properly indexed. Second, you might consider storing the birthdate in separate `Date` and `Time` columns (assuming you're using SQL Server 2008 or above, where the `Time` type was introduced). This will allow you to not only create a more succinct query (just one comparison on the date rather than three on the year, month, and day), but will also be much faster. Even if you index the birthdate column in the table, the index will be ignored because you're transforming the value (the query will use `DATEPART`).

If you split the birthdate column into separate columns, then place an index on those three columns (in name, birthdate, birthtime order), you should have a very quick query.

Comment: Yes, I am using Entity Framework. Unfortunately, splitting the Date field is not an option for this project. Thanks for your suggestion and I will keep this in mind for the next project.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "compare each record to other records in the same table" it sounds a little like you're describing grouping. If your comparison involves multiple greater than/less than comparisons it could be tricky, but as long as you're checking equality maybe something like this would work:

```
var secondAnimalsBornInDay =
    from animal in context.Animals
    group animal 
    by new 
    {
        animal.Name,
        animal.Birthday.Day,
        animal.Birthday.Month,
        animal.Birthday.Year,
    } 
    into groupOfAnimalsWithSameNameAndBirthday
    select groupOfAnimalsWithSameNameAndBirthday
           .OrderByDescending(a => a.Birthday)
           .Skip(1)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

That gives you a list of animals which were the second animal with their name to be born on the day on which they were born. Is that what you're looking for, or have I misunderstood the results of your example code? (Note that `secondAnimalsBornInDay` will contain nulls for each animal which was the only animal with its name to be born on the day it was born, so you'll need to filter those out.)

Comment: Steve, Thank you for your answer. Your solution does work for this scenario, however I would like to find a way around using the .Skip(1), if possible. Hard coding a value like that seems limiting.

Comment: `Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()` is the simplest way I know to get the second item in an IQueryable. Actually, I'm not sure how else you could do it.